# Edit or create depending on boolean value

Tags: mongodb, go

I have an objects in my collection that might contain a boolean variable called verified, or not.

If it does have this variable and it is false then I want to set it to true.

If it does not have this variable then I want to create it as true.

```
query := bson.D{{Key: "email", Value: email}}
update := bson.D{
    {Key: "$set",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "verified", Value: true},
        },
    },
}
 

err := col.Collection("objects").FindOneAndUpdate(context.Background(), &query, &update).Err()
```

I have tried:

```
    upsert := true
    opts := options.FindOneAndUpdateOptions{
        Upsert: &upsert,
    }

    filter := bson.D{{Key: "email", Value: email}}
    query := bson.D{
        {Key: "$set",
            Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "verified", Value: true},
            },
        },
    }

 err := col.Collection("objects").FindOneAndUpdate(context.Background(), &filter, &query, &opts).Err()
```

But it does not set the verified to true if the verified value does not exist. And even if it does exist and is false, it still isn't set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using upsert: true?

upsert:

- Creates a new document if no documents match the filter Updates a
  single document that matches the filter.

try passing upsert:true in findOneAndUpdate()

Comment: But this entire object already exists, I just want to create the variable inside it if the value does not exist or set it to true if the value is false?

Comment: also where would I set this? thanks. unknown field 'upsert' in struct literal of type primitive.E

Comment: you can pass it as optional parameter

Comment: I updated my answer to add new info, thank you